# How to transfer application into device when testing inapp purchases

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I found this information on a blog which talks about invalid product ids.
http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/

> I tried everything suggested in the
>   Apple forums and here, and still
>   couldn’t get it to work. Found the
>   solution – your app needs to be
>   transferred by Xcode for the sandbox
>   to be enabled.
>
> Obvious, right? Well, if you are
>   working with an update to an existing
>   account, the device will still treat
>   it as an App Store-installed app.
>
> Delete it, then transfer it again. It should work now :)

i am also getting invalid product ids.i am not able to get clear in the above said point...
i am not able to understand what i need to do when transferring the application into device...

Kindly guide me out and thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

That point just means that you need to run the app from Xcode in order for the sandbox to be available. (Build and Run)

Invalid product ids are a major pain to debug. If you're sure you've gotten everything on that checklist, then you just need to wait. Then only other problem that I've seen is that **you might need to remove the app from the device and redeploy** in order to get good products back from the store.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble getting the app store to recognize my sandbox test account. I had to log out wit *iTunes*, sync, then log in again with *iTunes*. Just using the device itself to log in/out didn't help.